# Need explanation for this case. [Proxy, Fiddler, HTTPS]

Tags: https, proxy, fiddler

As far as I know, SSL traffic cannot be decrypted without the proper certificate.

OK.

But why when I use cURL on PHP, and set it to go through Fiddler proxy on another host:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "192.168.2.182");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "8888");
```

I still can see the created [Tunnels:443] and read HTTPS traffic without installing Fiddler's Certificate on the host running the PHP code.

PHP (linux) <---------------> Fiddler (192.168.2.182) <---------------> (Server:443)

Can someone explain what is happening here?

Comment: From the sound of it, you haven't configured curl to validate that the server (Fiddler) has provided a valid certificate chain. http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Comment: This is covered in the Fiddler FAQ: [Certificates in Fiddler](http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-08-19/faq---certificates-in-fiddler).  In order for Fiddler to negotiate a session with the client, the client needs to either ignore Fiddler's certificate, or trust the root certificate that Fiddler generates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From the sound of it, you haven't configured curl to validate that the
>   server (Fiddler) has provided a valid certificate chain.
>   curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html - [EricLaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126229/ericlaw)

I wish this was posted as an answer.